# Calculate dark noise in CCD given a pixel's counts for two exposures

Tags: noise, camera

Suppose I took two pictures with the same CCD camera in totally dark room.
The first picture was exposed for 1 microsecond, and the pixel given was 20 scales of grey.
The second picture was exposed for 10 seconds, and the pixel given was 60 scales of grey.

How can I calculate the dark noise of the CCD camera?
Or at least to determine the size/difference of the dark noise`s change?

Comment: This question may be better addressed in the Photography SE. Also consider and demonstrate what you already know about the sources of noise in a case of perfect dark count. How is it affected by time?

Comment: At early times, the total noise is more likely to be dominated by the CCD readout noise. At longer exposure times, the total noise is more likely to be dominated by the dark current. So to me it seems natural to take a series of exposures and do a linear fit on the $e^{-}_{RMS}/s$. Assuming the temperature of the CCD is well-regulated, the increase in dark counts should be pretty linear as a function of time I think.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Thats the connection that I`m missing - I know that there is an exponential relation between the data collection chip and time, but got no clue how to prove it. In some attempts to solve the issue i found that the variation of the CCD camera is constant - about 4 scales of grey per second.

Answer (score 0):

In perfect dark room each pixel of a perfect CCD would yield the grey scale zero. However, real CCDs are not perfect. Therefore, each pixel accumulates a grey scale level greater than zero. This is due to "random noise sources". Usually we expect that this dark noise increases with the so called integration time (=time period of the measurement) -- note, that this is not the case in your example. However, since the dark noise is due to a random process we do *not* always obtain the same grey scale level: If we take 100 measurements, each with the integration time $T=100\mu s$, we do not obtain the same result each time, but obtain a distribution. The two most important characteristics of this distribution are (usually) the *average* and the *standard deviation* for each pixel.

Note, that there exists [different random noise sources](https://www.photometrics.com/resources/technotes/pdfs/snr.pdf) in a CCD chip. Therefore, we expect that the dark noise spectrum exhibits some characteristic frequencies, where the noise spectrum changes its shape. Thus, in order to get the dark noise spectrum you have to take measurements with different integration times. However, if you are only interested in a *worst case estimate* of the dark noise, a "very long" integration time is sufficient.

Comment: the link says the dark noise is, just like photon shot noise, Poissonian in nature. So spectrum is more-or-less featureless (flat). And the noise power increases linearly with time. A series of exposures with long integration times gives you a good estimate of the dark noise - not better or worse, it IS the way to measure.

Comment: Suppose i wanted to neglect all the side parameter`s (just for understanding the theory), can i assume that the variation of the shades of grey(bit`s) on each readout node will be changed exponentialy for every 1 sec approximately ?